# Parse Date from text file for JTable

Tags: java, swing, date, jtable, text-files

I'm trying to parse dates from my text file `rents`:

```
06.06.2018.|16.06.2018.|13|Gost|Gostic|617000|false
08.06.2018.|14.06.2018.|12|Guest|Guestic|617000|false
```

So I set format `("dd.MM.yyyy.")`

```
DateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy.");

String startDate = split[0];
Date startDatePars = sourceFormat.parse(startDate);

String endDate = split[1];
Date endDatePars = sourceFormat.parse(endDate);
```

But when I want to show it in JTable it's show like:

[image]

But I want it to display on the same way as it is in text file.

How to do that?

**EDIT**

```
static ArrayList<Rent> loadRents() {
        ArrayList<Rent> rents = new ArrayList<Rent>();
        try {
            File rentsFile = new File("src/txt/rents");
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(rentsFile));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] split = line.split("\\|");
                DateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy.");
                String startDate = split[0];
                Date startDatePars = sourceFormat.parse(startDate);
                String endDate = split[1];
                Date endDatePars = sourceFormat.parse(endDate);
                String roomNumber = split[2];
                String guestName = split[3];
                String guestLastname = split[4];
                String guestIDCard = split[5];
                Boolean deleted = Boolean.parseBoolean(split[5]);
                if (deleted)
                    continue;
                Rent newRent = new Rent(startDatePars, endDatePars, roomNumber, guestName, guestLastname, guestIDCard, deleted);
                rents.add(newRent);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rents;
    }
```

Populating JTable:

```
ArrayList<Rent> rents = loadRents();
        String[] header = new String[] {"Star date", "End date", "Room number","Guest name", "Guest lastname", "Guest ID card"};
        Object[][] show = new Object[rents.size()][header.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < rents.size(); i++) {
            Rent r = rents.get(i);
            show[i][0] = r.getDateStart();
            show[i][1] = r.getDateEnd();
            show[i][2] = r.getRoomNumber();
            show[i][3] = r.getGuestName();
            show[i][4] = r.getGuestLastname();
            show[i][5] = r.getGuestIDCard();

            DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(show, header);
            tblRents = new JTable(tableModel);
            tblRents.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
            tblRents.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
            tblRents.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
            tblRents.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, null);
            tblRents.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
```

Comment: You have to format it again to the correct format, or show it like it is(String)

Comment: @YCF_L again? Why? Where? How?

Comment: can you show us how you fill your JTable please?

Comment: @YCF_L Just edited.

Comment: try this `show[i][0] = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy.").format(r.getDateStart());` and `show[i][1] = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy.").format(r.getDateEnd());` but I strongly suggest to use [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) API when you work with dates it is more helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `LocalDate` instead of `Date` and try this version it should work...

```
String content = "06.06.2018.|16.06.2018.|13|Gost|Gostic|617000|false";
String [] split = content.split("\\|");

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy.");

LocalDate dateBegin = LocalDate.parse(split[0], formatter);
LocalDate dateEnd = LocalDate.parse(split[1], formatter);

System.out.println(dateBegin); // 2018-06-06
System.out.println(dateEnd); // 2018-06-16
```

**EDIT** Thanks to [YCF_L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5558072/ycf-l) for the hint regarding the formatting of output:

```
System.out.println(dateBegin.format(formatter)); // 06.06.2018.
System.out.println(dateEnd.format(formatter)); // 16.06.2018.
```

Comment: The OP should also change the startDatePars and endDatePars of the Rent object then in the other side when you want to set the date to JTabale note that the default format is `yyyy-MM-dd` so you have to format it again unless you want to stuck with this format :)